# Static vs Dynamic Linking

Tags: c, gcc, linker, static-linking, dynamic-linking

I'm trying to understand how the ELF looks like for a statically vs. a dynamically linked program.

I understand that this is how static linking works:
[image]

In my case, I have two files, `foo.c` and `bar.c`.
I also have their object files; `foo.o` and `bar.o`.
With the `objdump` command, I can see the relocations in each file.

How do I **statically** link the `foo.o` and `bar.o`?

How do I **dynamically** link the `foo.o` and `bar.o`?

How can I see the difference in the output files?

Answer (score 3):

Linking dynamically is the default mode of most linkers these days. If you want to link statically you have to use the `-static` flag when linking. To clarify, when I say "linking dynamically" versus "linking statically" I mean the linking with external libraries, and not generating a library that in turn can be linked (dynamically or statically).

The difference can't be seen in the object files you pass to the linker, as it has nothing to do with the compiler and object-file generation, the result can only be seen in the resulting executable program after linking, and the biggest difference is that the executable will most likely be larger.

The resulting and fully linked executable will be larger because then all the libraries (for which there are static libraries) will actually be linked into the executable program quite literally. It's basically including the libraries object files together with your own object files. Actually, on POSIX platforms static libraries are just archives of object files.

Comment: Your answer is a little bit misleading. Object files on the linker command line are always linked statically with one-another, the `-static` flag only pertains library operands. It would be great if you could put this in context of the question (how to link `foo.o` and `bar.o`...).

Comment: In particular, neither `main.o` nor `swap.o` will create dynamically loaded shared objects.

Comment: @FUZxxl Can you please give to command to link source files statically and dynamically?

What's the difference between linking source files and libraries?

Comment: How can I examine the process address space of a statically/dynamically linked program?

Comment: @AdegokeA When you invoke the linker, object files are always linked statically with one-another. That's what a linker does. Dynamic vs. static linking only pertains library operands (i.e. `-lsomething`) and then you supply `-shared` or `-static` depending on what you want.

Comment: @FUZxxl This works `gcc -o foobar_sh -shared foo.c bar.c`.

But this doesn't `gcc -o foobar_st -static foo.c bar.c`.

What am I  doing wrong?

Comment: @AdegokeA With static linking (unless `-r` is passed to the linker in which case the output is again an object file), the result is a whole program. If `foo.c` and `bar.c` do not form a full program, static linking fails. I was wrong above, `-shared` creates a *shared object*, `-dynamic` does dynamic linking. `-shared` works because that creates a shared library which does not need to be complete.